# Memory effective way to transform collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this in mongodb:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a5f47ed420cf0db5b70242"),
        "tag" : "swift",
        "values" : [
                {
                        "word" : "osx",
                        "value" : 0.02
                },
                {
                        "word" : "compiler",
                        "value" : 0.01
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a5f47ed420cf0db5b70243"),
        "tag" : "c++",
        "values" : [
                {
                        "word" : "namespace",
                        "value" : 0.04
                },
                {
                        "word" : "compiler",
                        "value" : 0.05
                }
        ]
}
```

I need to transform it in collection like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a5f4e5d420cf0db5b70247"),
        "word" : "namespace",
        "values" : [
                {
                        "tag" : "c++",
                        "value" : 0.04
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a5f4e5d420cf0db5b70248"),
        "word" : "compiler",
        "values" : [
                {
                        "tag" : "swift",
                        "value" : 0.01
                },
                {
                        "tag" : "c++",
                        "value" : 0.05
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a5f4e5d420cf0db5b70249"),
        "word" : "osx",
        "values" : [
                {
                        "tag" : "swift",
                        "value" : 0.02
                }
        ]
}
```

I'm new to working with a mongodb and MapReduce and have some questions:

1. Should I use MapReduce or Aggregation framework with $out to another collection in my case?
2. Which an approach is more memory effective? Because a collection is large (3gb) and I have only 8gb of RAM, I'm afraid of getting an OutOfMemory error.
3. If I will use MapReduce, what should be in map and reduce stages? I should emit items like `{"word": word, "values": {"tag":tag, "value": value} }` in map stage and merge it into reduce state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method.

You need to denormalize the "values" array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator. The last stage in the pipeline is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you group your document by "values.word" and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator to return and array of sub-documents for each group.

From there, you can insert your documents into a new collection using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations.

```js
var bulk = db.myCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count  = 0;
db.collection.aggregate( [ 
    { "$unwind": "$values" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$values.word", 
        "values": { 
             "$push": { "tag": "$tag", "value": "$values.value" } 
        } 
    } }
]).forEach(function(doc) { 
    bulk.insert( { "word": doc._id, "values": doc.values } );
    count++;
    if ( count % 1000 === 0 ) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.myCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});
// Clean up queues
if (count > 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```